# An inequality involving n-th real root of real numbers

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Given any $1\leq K\leq a$ and $1\leq K\leq b^{1/n}, $ $n$ is any positive integer, I was trying to prove

$$\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b^{1/n}}-\frac{1}{1+(ab)^{1/(n+1)}}\leq \frac{1}{1+K},$$ where $x^{1/n}$ represents nth real root of $x.$
Will the induction principle help?

Comment: It doesn't hold for [$n=2, a=1, b=2, K = \sqrt{2}\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F(1%2Ba)+%2B+1%2F(1%2Bsurd(b,n))+-+1%2F(1%2Bsurd(ab,n%2B1))+-+1%2F(1%2Bk)+-+0.05+where+n%3D2,+a%3D1,+b%3D2,+k%3Dsurd(b,n)). Is there more context of where this inequality comes from, or why it would be expected to hold true?

Comment: It came to my thought and might be a useful inequality. I think the inequality might be true if $b^{1/n}$ is made large comparing to $K$ and the problem can be re-presented  and proved accordingly. The point $b=a_1a_2...a_n$  is related conceptually  with $a$ and $K$ as  $a_i\geq K.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHS of the inequality is decreasing with $K$, so for inequality to hold in general it is enough that it holds for the minimum value of the RHS, which is attained for the maximum $K=\sqrt[n]{b}\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+a}+\cancel{\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[n]{b}}}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[n+1]{ab}}\leq \cancel{\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[n]{b}}} \;\;&\iff\;\; \frac{1}{1+a} \le \frac{1}{1+\sqrt[n+1]{ab}} \\
 &\iff\;\; \cancel{1}+\sqrt[n+1]{ab} \le \cancel{1} + a \\
 &\iff\;\; \bcancel{a}b \le a^{n+\bcancel{1}} \\
 &\iff\;\; \sqrt[n]{b} \le a
\end{align}
$$

Therefore the posted inequality does not hold in general, but the following reformulation does:

> Given $1\leq K\leq \sqrt[n]{b} \le a\,$, $n \in \mathbb{N}\,$: $\;\;\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[n]{b}}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[n+1]{ab}}\leq \frac{1}{1+K}\,$.